# Script should send an email containing form submission values, but no email is getting sent

Tags: php, html, email, forms

So I have a HTML form with some PHP but I'm not getting any email whatsoever after submitting it. I can't find the problem! can you help me out?

- Tried changing the if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { to 'enviar' but still not working.
- tried putting some echos to see where it's not working. the only statement that is stopping at the else statement is stripslashes.

The form snippet:

```
<div id="contact-wrapper">

    <?php if(isset($hasError)) { //If errors are found ?>
        <p class="error">Please check if you entered valid information.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if(isset($emailSent) && $emailSent == true) { //If email is sent ?>
        <p><strong>Email sent with success!</strong></p>
        <p>Thank you for using our contact form <strong><?php echo $name;?></strong>, we will contact you soon.</p>
    <?php } ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="contactform">
        <div>
            <label for="name"><strong>Name:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="email"><strong>E-mail:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required email" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="subject"><strong>Subject:</strong></label>
            <input type="text" size="50" name="subject" id="subject" value="" class="required" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="message"><strong>Message:</strong></label>
            <textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="message" id="message" class="required"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar" name="submit" id="submit" />
    </form>
    </div>
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
//If the form is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);
    }

    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    }

    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'myemail@email.com'; //Put your own email address here
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: add print_r($_POST) to the top of your php, what's it return?

Comment: If it is stopping at the stripslashes it's safe to assume that it is detecting your submit button. Try doing `die(var_dump($_POST));` instead of echo and follow it all the way down to the mail function.

Comment: this is wonderful `function_exists('stripslashes')` . Is this code from php 3 epoch?

Comment: If `stripslashes` is yielding problems, why not skip it? Just replace that `if-else` block by the contents of the `else`. The worst that could happen (although it shouldn't) is that your message comes enclosed on quotes.

Comment: @Dagon - It gives me an error in the beggining of my statement.

Comment: @herenvardo - I rremoved the if else on stripslashes and put $comments = trim($_POST['message']); still not working though

Answer (score 5):

Before getting any email, you have to be sure the email is being *sent*.

```
$sent = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
var_dump($sent);
```

What does this code output when placed in the appropriate place?

Comment: Which means that the mail was sent (or the server at least thinks so). Next step should be to verify the address, and your spam filters.

Comment: tried on a gmail, hotmail and an email from the host, still not working, turned SPAM filters off, checked all folders for new posts, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simple php page to do a test Email (eg fixed content) and I assume the webserver has email configured and is prepared to relay for your address?

Comment: everything configured and prepared

Comment: Do you run your mail server, can you see if its being rejected on your end? - as an example, my mail server for my domain wont accept mails from my domain if it doesnt come from my local network.. It regards it as cheating.

Comment: not running on my own, paid server with mail support. I've tried doing this before and it worked although the form was much simpler and didn't have all the validations and if else statements.

Comment: Thats why I suggested the fixed email, just to prove a mail can make it from a->b

Comment: What exactly do you mean with fixed content? can you give me an example?

Comment: Such as main("Me@home.com","test message","This is a test message from my mail server","From: me@home.com"); So it removes any thing other than your mail server blocking it (as you've already proved in the above question that the mail server thinks its sending it, the next thing to do is prove your mail server isnt eating it. Is your web hoster also your Email hoster? If not have you used the pair of companies before? eg, are you really sure that the mail hoster doesnt need to be told to allow certain servers to send as you (lots do these days to reduce spam)

Comment: OK, so its objecting either to the content, or something else, step through the parts till you find the bits is objecting to, and work up from there. As it sounds like its a problem you need to identify with the web hoster and its objecting to something in the mail as either spam, malicious etc.

Answer (score -1):

If this is WordPress contact form, for starters:

```
mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

should be:

```
wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

See: [wp_mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) codex

Now you have to check your e-mail setup, as well as WordPress e-mail setup too.

Comment: I don't think the OP references Wordpress anywhere...?